# sql query to get previous and current record based on other column rank value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a source table attached below:

[image]

I want to have a output result which shows the latest status of company along with its previous status in a keyword **latest**

below is the output format:

[image]

I have tried below query and was thinking to achieve the result by ranking the each status

```
select 
    company_name,
    status as latest
    status as status_update,
    case when status = 'todo' then 1
        when status = 'inprogress' then 2
        when status = 'completed' then 3
        else 0 end as no
from TABLE
```

output:

[image]

Any help in proceeding with this to get **prev** and **current** columns would be helpfull to get the result

Answer (score 1):

See example, without windows functions (ROW_NUMBER,LAG,LEAD ...)
Query schema is
1)Numbering statuses "by hand" - there no other kinds to ordering.(CTE "status_num")
2)Take max status No for company - group by company_name.(Subquery "m")
3)Take status with max No - latest, and with (max No-1) - previous.

```
with status_num as (
select company_name ,status 
    ,case when status = 'todo' then 1
        when status = 'inprogress' then 2
        when status = 'completed' then 3
     else 0 
     end as no
from test
)
select s.company_name,'latest' as keywords
  ,max(case when no=max_no then status end) latest
  ,max(case when no=(max_no-1) then status end) prev
from status_num s
left join (
    select company_name,max(no)max_no 
    from status_num group by company_name
  ) m  on m.company_name=s.company_name
group by s.company_name
```

With test data

```
insert into test values
 ('A','todo','2023-09-10')
,('A','inprogress','2023-09-10')
,('A','completed' ,'2023-09-10')
,('B','todo' ,'2023-09-11')
,('B','inprogress' ,'2023-09-11')
,('C','todo' ,'2023-09-12')
;
```

Output is

| Company_name | keywords | latest | prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | latest | completed | inprogress |
| B | latest | inprogress | todo |
| C | latest | todo | null |

Comment: @VaNik Thanks for the response. As I had mentioned the output format in description how can achieve that from the obtained result? where I want to have a column as keyword and have previous and current records as values. will unpivot work here?

Comment: Answer is updated.